# When I divide two numbers in Java, no decimal found

Tags: java, numbers, decimal

I write a code in Java

I have two numbers

For example

```
int alas  = 15;
int tinggi = 3;
```

When I divide those two numbers

```
int luas = (alas * tinggi) / 2;
```

I want to have 7.5 as a result, but why it keeps shown as 7.0

Comment: Because of `int` calculations.

Comment: use `float` .....or `double`

Comment: `luas` is an `int`, it can't output `7.0`...

Comment: *Integer division*. Use `0.5 * alas * tinggi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` there is no decimal places. you can use `double` or `float`.

```
double luas = (alas * tinggi) / 2.0;
```

Comment: the part at the end - 2.0 - is very important, if it was just 2, then the result would have a decimal place, but it would always be 0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
double luas = (alas * tinggi) / 2.0;
```

when you divide int by int you will have int result. `2.0` mean that you want to divide by double, so result will be double.